# Remove space from regex expression in php

Tags: php, regex

I have a php echo with regular expression as in

```
echo preg_replace("/(\[|\])/", '', $paramValue);
```

I also want to make sure that any spaces are replaced aka if we have hello / world it becomes hello/world

I am not good with regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

For just space you can use:

```
$string = str_replace(' ', '', $string);
```

For whitespaces you can use:

```
$string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

### [Regex](http://regex101.com/r/cL7kT9)

```
(\[|\]| )
```

### PHP

```
echo preg_replace("/(\[|\]| )/", '', $paramValue);
```

**Description**

```
1st Capturing group (\[|\]| )
    1st Alternative: \[
        \[ matches the character [ literally
    2nd Alternative: \]
        \] matches the character ] literally
    3rd Alternative:  
        matches the character   literally
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this  for removing space using regular expression.

```
$string = "hello / world";
$string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string);
echo $string;
```

result:

**hello/world**

Answer (score 0):

Thanks this is what I did

```
            utag_data.ad_sec<?php echo ($i+1); ?> = "<?php 
                preg_replace("/(\[|\]) /", '', $paramValue);
                $paramValue = str_replace(' ', '', $paramValue); 
                echo $paramValue;
            ?>";
```